# Match skin tone in a black and white photo

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-match

How can I match skin tone colors in a black and white photo, using Photoshop? I am trying to learn how to turn a photo into a digital painting with this process.

I used desaturation on a colored photo, then used the smudge tool to create a paint effect, then colored them using different modes. However I can't seem to match the skin tones in black and white color, so that when I color them it will look natural.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Thanks for the question and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions about how the site works

Comment: Do you mean you want to add the color back to the grayscale image?

Answer (score 1):

Use the clone tool to paint with the actual skin pixels. All of the tones that you need are already there in the photo. If you need to, use a second copy of the photo (in another window) as the source for the clone tool.